# Projects that use composite pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, composite

what kind of projects use the composite pattern? How am I supposed to know what project is using the composite pattern?

Comment: Java Swing Framework. Panels and Components are composed objects

Comment: why is swing framework a composite pattern?

Comment: Because there's a natural class ordering of a top level component, then specific types of those that can be added within it, such as a panel or button. You can reference the overall component with its children as a single element, which just happens to compose the others

Comment: Java swing's `Container` is a `Component` and has child `Component`s. Thus it is a composite pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deep learning framework "PyTorch" uses the composed pattern for Model.

Comment: know any java projects?